# Impossible to uninstall miktex

Tags: miktex2.9

I am unable to uninstall miktex. I have not run the console before the desinstallation and now i cannot reinstall a fresh miktex. Help please

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `del C:`? Just joking. `;-)` I'm sure somebody will give better advice.

Comment: Why can't you reinstall? When I switched to 64 bit some days ago I couldn't deinstall either (probably one of the windows upgrades messed it up), but I simply removed the miktex folder and installed anyway and had no problems (I have a single user installation in win10).

Comment: As Ulrike already noted, it should be enough to simply delete the MikTeX program folder.. also look in your C:/Users/YourName/ hidden folder for any saved application settings for MikTeX. In the most extreme case, you can use CCleaner (free program) to remove any Windows registry data. Then, I advise you to install the "portable" version of MikTeX. Many users report installation problems with the non-portable version, few to none with the portable version.